# enable reverse engieneer spring roo 2.0.0.M2

Tags: mysql, reverse, spring-roo

Hi I want to uso Spring roo, but how do I enable database instrospect sentence?
The documentation says that jpa in this roo version is a addon [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-roo/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/#base-overview) but after invoke `jpa setup --provider --database`  a springboot example is enable but no `applicationContext.xml` file is created, and thus I cannot  enable reverse engieneer spring roo   2.0.0.M2.
after executing `addon suite start --symbolicName  org.springframework.roo.wrapping.mysql-connector-java`
the database introspect is not enable and this appears `Searching 'database introspect' on installed repositories
0 matches found with 'database introspect' on installed repositories`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Roo 2.0.0.M2 is the second milestone of Spring Roo 2.0 version. That means that it's not a final release and maybe some features that were available on previous Spring Roo versions could be not complete or could be unavailable on this one.

Here are the differences between the versions names:

GA = General availability (a release); should be very stable and feature complete

RC = Release candidate; probably feature complete and should be pretty stable - problems should be relatively rare and minor, but worth reporting to try to get them fixed for release.

M = Milestone build - probably not feature complete; should be vaguely stable (i.e. it's more than just a nightly snapshot) but may still have problems.

Ansewering your question about database reverse engineer, we are analyzing the posibility to migrate this Spring Roo 1.x feature to Spring Roo 2.x version to be able to use [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org) to mantain the generated model and the related DB using Spring Roo shell. So, maybe this functionality will be available on the next Spring Roo Milestone version or release candidate.

For now, if you want to use database reverse engineer you should try with Spring Roo 2.0.0.M1 (maybe applied changes for that version don't affect to reverse engineer) or with Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE.

Check out the [Spring Roo JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO) to know the Spring Roo roadmap. Feel free to report new issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that dbre (database reverse engineering) was even being called into question with version 2. I see this feature as a one of the big ones that separates spring roo from jhipster, and one of the main reasons I continue to use it.